# Visualize TFLite graph and get intermediate values of a particular node?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I was wondering if there is a way to know the list of inputs and outputs for a particular node in tflite? I know that I can get input/outputs details, but this does not allow me to reconstruct the computation process that happens inside an `Interpreter`. So what I do is:

```python
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()
interpreter.get_tensor_details()
```

The last 3 commands basically give me dictionaries which don't seem to have the necessary information.

So I was wondering if there is way to know where each nodes outputs goes? Surely `Interpreter` knows this somehow. Can we? Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Note:** this answer was written for Tensorflow 1.x and, while the concept and core idea remains the same in TensorFlow 2.x, the commands in this answer might be deprecated.

The mechanism of TF-Lite makes the whole process of inspecting the graph and getting the intermediate values of inner nodes a bit tricky. The `get_tensor(...)` method suggested by the other answer does not work.

## How to visualize TF-Lite inference graph?

TensorFlow Lite models can be visualized using the [visualize.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/visualize.py) script in the [TensorFlow Lite repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite). You just need to:

- [Clone the TensorFlow repository](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)
- Run the `visualize.py` script with bazel:

  ```
    bazel run //tensorflow/lite/tools:visualize \
         model.tflite \
         visualized_model.html
  ```

## Does the nodes in my TF model have a equivalent one in TF-Lite?

**NO!** In fact, TF-Lite can modify your graph so that it become more optimal. Here are some words about it from the [TF-Lite documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility):

> A number of TensorFlow operations can be processed by TensorFlow Lite even though they have no direct equivalent. This is the case for operations that can be simply removed from the graph (tf.identity), replaced by tensors (tf.placeholder), or fused into more complex operations (tf.nn.bias_add). Even some supported operations may sometimes be removed through one of these processes.

Moreover, the TF-Lite API currently doesn't allow to get node correspondence; it's hard to interpret the inner format of TF-Lite. So, you can't get the intermediate outputs for any nodes you want, even without the one more issue below...

## Can I get intermediate values of some TF-Lite nodes?

**NO!** Here, I will explain why [`get_tensor(...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_tensor) wouldn't work in TF-Lite. Suppose in the inner representation, the graph contains of 3 tensors, together with some dense operations (nodes) in-between (you can think of `tensor1` as input and `tensor3` as output of your model). During inference of this particular graph, TF-Lite **only** needs 2 buffers, let's show how.

**First,** use `tensor1` to compute `tensor2` by applying `dense` operation. This only requires 2 buffers to store the values:

```
           dense              dense
[tensor1] -------> [tensor2] -------> [tensor3]
 ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^
 bufferA            bufferB
```

**Second,** use the value of `tensor2` stored in `bufferB` to compute `tensor3`... but wait! We don't need `bufferA` anymore, so let's use it to store the value of `tensor3`:

```
           dense              dense
[tensor1] -------> [tensor2] -------> [tensor3]
                    ^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^
                    bufferB            bufferA
```

Now is the tricky part. The "output value" of `tensor1` will still point to `bufferA`, which now holds the values of `tensor3`. So if you call [`get_tensor(...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_tensor) for the 1st tensor, you'll get incorrect values. The [documentation of this method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/lite/Interpreter#get_tensor) even states:

> This function cannot be used to read intermediate results.

## How to get around this?

- **Easy but limited way.** You can specify the names of the nodes, output tensors of which you want to get the values of during conversion:

  ```bash
    tflite_convert \
        -- # other options of your model
        --output_arrays="output_node,intermediate/node/n1,intermediate/node/n2"
  ```
- **Hard but flexible way.** You can compile TF-Lite with Bazel (using [this instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)). Then you can actually inject some logging code to `Interpreter::Invoke()` in the file `tensorflow/lite/interpreter.cc`. An ugly hack, but it works.

Comment: This is a great explanation! Thank you so much. I am sure many other people will find it useful. I'm accepting it

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to run but do you know how can I actually see the visualized model?

Comment: After waiting 3+ hrs for the entire tf to build, I found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/examples/minimal): If you just care about running inference with TFLite, you can build this minimal sample (takes about 20 mins)

Comment: @akevan that's a great find! It's been few years since last time I worked with TFLite, but if I remember correctly, you can `cd` into the right folder and `bazel build` just the project that you need. You don't have to build entire TF, just TFLite (or even parts of TFLite). Each build took me 2-3 minutes so I could quickly iterate.

Answer (score 1):

As @FalconUA has pointed out, we cannot directly get intermediate inputs and outputs from a TFlite model. But, we can get inputs and outputs of layers by modifying the model buffer. [This repo](https://github.com/raymond-li/tflite_tensor_outputter) shows how it is done. We need to modify flat buffer schema for this to work. The modified TFlite schema (`tflite` folder in the repo) is available in the repo.

For the completeness of the answer, below is the relevant code:

```
def buffer_change_output_tensor_to(model_buffer, new_tensor_i):
    # from https://github.com/raymond-li/tflite_tensor_outputter
    # Set subgraph 0's output(s) to new_tensor_i
    # Reads model_buffer as a proper flatbuffer file and gets the offset programatically
    # It might be much more efficient if Model.subgraphs[0].outputs[] was set to a list of all the tensor indices.
    fb_model_root = tflite_model.Model.GetRootAsModel(model_buffer, 0)
    output_tensor_index_offset = fb_model_root.Subgraphs(0).OutputsOffset(0) # Custom added function to return the file offset to this vector
    # print("buffer_change_output_tensor_to. output_tensor_index_offset: ")
    # print(output_tensor_index_offset)
    # output_tensor_index_offset = 0x5ae07e0 # address offset specific to inception_v3.tflite
    # output_tensor_index_offset = 0x16C5A5c # address offset specific to inception_v3_quant.tflite
    # Flatbuffer scalars are stored in little-endian.
    new_tensor_i_bytes = bytes([
        new_tensor_i & 0x000000FF, \
        (new_tensor_i & 0x0000FF00) >> 8, \
        (new_tensor_i & 0x00FF0000) >> 16, \
        (new_tensor_i & 0xFF000000) >> 24 \
    ])
    # Replace the 4 bytes corresponding to the first output tensor index
    return model_buffer[:output_tensor_index_offset] + new_tensor_i_bytes + model_buffer[output_tensor_index_offset + 4:]

def get_tensor(path_tflite, tensor_id):
    with open(path_tflite, 'rb') as fp:
        model_buffer = fp.read()
    
    model_buffer = buffer_change_output_tensor_to(model_buffer, int(tensor_id))
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=model_buffer)
    interpreter.allocate_tensors()
    tensor_details = interpreter._get_tensor_details(tensor_id)
    tensor_name = tensor_details['name']
    
    input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], input_tensor)
    interpreter.invoke()
    
    tensor = interpreter.get_tensor(tensor_id)
    return tensor
```