# SavedModel - TFLite - SignatureDef - TensorInfo - Get intermediate Layer outputs

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I would like to get intermediate layers output of a TFLite graph. Something in the lines of below.

[Visualize TFLite graph and get intermediate values of a particular node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885007/visualize-tflite-graph-and-get-intermediate-values-of-a-particular-node)

The above solution works on frozen graphs only. Since SavedModel is the preferred way of serializing the model in TF 2.0, I would like to have a solution with a saved model. I tried to pass --output_arrays for "toco" with savedModelDir as input. This is not helping.

From the documentation, it looks like SignatureDefs in SavedModel is the option to achieve this. But, I could not get it working.

```
x = test_images[0:1]
output = model.predict(x, batch_size=1)

signature_def = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
          inputs={name:"x:0", dtype: DT_FLOAT, tensor_shape: (1, 28,28, 1)})          
          outputs = {{name: "output:0", dtype: DT_FLOAT, tensor_shape: (1, 10)},
                     {name:"Dense_1:0", dtype: DT_FLOAT, tensor_shape: (1, 10)}})


tf.saved_model.save(model, './tf-saved-model-sigdefs', signature_def)
```

Can you share an example usage of SignatureDefs for this purpose?
BTW, I have been playing around with the below tutorial for this experiment.
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/images/intro_to_cnns

Answer (score 1):

`tf.lite.Interpreter` has a new parameter as of tf 2.5: `experimental_preserve_all_tensors`, when set to `True` it allows you to query the output from any node.  Here is how I used it:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Use tensorflow framework to determine class')
parser.add_argument('--model-path', '-m', default='model.tflite', type=str, help='path to the model')
parser.add_argument('--nodes', '-n', default='concat,convert_scores', type=str, help='comma separated list of node names')
parser.add_argument('--image', '-i', default='test.jpg', type=str, help='image to process')

args = parser.parse_args()

# read in model
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(
 args.model_path, experimental_preserve_all_tensors=True
)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

# prepare image
img = cv2.imread(args.image)
inp = cv2.resize(img, tuple(input_details[0]["shape"][1:3]))
inp = inp[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]  # BGR2RGB
inp = inp[np.newaxis, :, :, :].astype(input_details[0]["dtype"])

# invoke mode
interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]["index"], inp)
interpreter.invoke()

# write out layer output to files
for node in args.nodes.split(','):
    for tensor_details in interpreter.get_tensor_details():
        if tensor_details["name"] == node:
            tensor = interpreter.get_tensor(tensor_details["index"])
            np.save(node, tensor)
            break
```

You can use `netron` to graphically view the network described by your tflite model file, the node names can be found by clicking on a node.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best solution that I have so far.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

#!pip install -q tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)


#Saving in saved_model format
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, './tf-saved-model')

#Saving in TFLIte FlatBUffer format
tflite_mnist_model = "mnist_model.tflite"
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_mnist_model, "wb").write(tflite_model)

#cloning Keras model with debug outputs
outputs = [model.get_layer("dense").output, model.get_layer("dense_1").output]
model_debug = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=outputs)

#Saving in TFLIte FlatBUffer format with debug information
tflite_mnist_model = "mnist_model_debug.tflite"
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model_debug)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(tflite_mnist_model, "wb").write(tflite_model)
```